# Why is the back button not showing up?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, ionic-framework

Can't for the life of me figure out why the back button doesn't show up when I navigate to an `<ion-view>`

`app` root state template:

```
<ion-side-menus>
  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <div class="list">
    <!-- ... -->  
    </div>
  </ion-side-menu>
  <ion-side-menu-content state>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
      <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <!-- Content -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

  </ion-side-menu-content>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Then, I have two simple views, one that gets loaded on app start and one that is linked from it with an `ui-sref`.

Default `app.entries` state template:

```
<ion-view title="Entries">
    <a ui-sref="app.entryDetails({ entryId: entry._id })" ng-repeat="entry in entryList"> {{entry.title}} </a>
</ion-view>
```

`app.entryDetails` state template:

```
<ion-view title="{{entry.title}}">
    Testing.
</ion-view>
```

And in the end, [this](https://gfycat.com/DeterminedFineGrasshopper) is what happens. Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: Codepen or plunkr to look at? Testing this out, I'm not able to replicate this.
http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/QwamEW

Answer (score -1):

Use the `ion-nav-back button`

```
<ion-view view-title="{{entry.tittle}}">
   <ion-nav-bar>
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
        <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
     </ion-nav-back-button>
   </ion-nav-bar>
  <ion-content>
   Testing
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the correct syntax. Wouldn't this ion-nav-bar clash with the ion-nav-bar in the root template for starters? Either way, it doesn't work.

Comment: What angular and ionic package versions are you using? I've noticed that the newer versions have broken my navigation ability. I would suggest reverting to these packages and seeing if your problems persist.

Comment: urigo:angular   0.9.3*, urigo:angular-ui-router 0.7.0,  urigo:angular-ui-router,urigo:ionic 1.0.0_1*

Comment: Thanks Nate, will try now